# Html5 video freezes in IE9 after a few seconds

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I'm using hmtl5 video. It works normally in all browsers, except IE9.
In IE9 it's cannot playing after first play, or video freezes after a few seconds, but video state is "playing". I've add eventlisteners to check it.
Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think IE9 has some issues regarding HTML5 Video. You shouldn't trust on that to work. Maybe a (flash) fallback for IE9 would be good. Most of those bugs are fixed in IE10. So HTML5 Video should work there (if you use the right video encodings).

http://caniuse.com/#search=video

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a flash player fallback for Internet Explorer 9 and other browsers with issues with HTML5 video.